# PriorityQueue is removing last element added (acting like a lifo)

Tags: java, queue

I need another pair of eyes to look at this problem. I have implemented both a Depth first Search and Breadth First Search for a problem I am trying to solve. The Queue/stack used based on the search uses Node objects.

The problem is, both search algorithms are returning the same sequence. After looking into it more, it seems that the Priority Queue in the BFS algorithm is making the newest element that is added the HEAD of the queue.

**Note**
I have also tried changing the datastructure as follow as it still gives the same result.

```
PriorityQueue <Node> fifo = new PriorityQueue <Node>();
```

I am following the conventional add and remove/poll method supplied by the interface. Below is the code for the BFS algorithm.

```
public static void BFS(Node initial, char [][] grid){
    Queue <Node> fifo = new LinkedList <Node>();
    ArrayList<Node> explored = new ArrayList<Node>();
    int l = 0;
    fifo.add(initial);
    //Make a method to test if there is any dirt remaining on the grid for THIS node
    boolean dirtExists = testDirt(initial.dirtCoordinates);
    //System.out.println("complete boolean value is: " + dirtExists);
    if(!dirtExists){
        //If no dirt, then we are done
    }
    else{
        while(dirtExists){
         //Test whether there are any more elements in the queue. If not, then done
            if(fifo.isEmpty()){
                break;
            }else{
                //Grab the next element in the queue
                Node nextNode = fifo.poll();
                explored.add(nextNode);
                System.out.println("First element removed " + nextNode.stringBuilder);
                if(testDirt(nextNode.dirtCoordinates)){
                    dirtExists = true;
                }else{

                    dirtExists = false;
                    break;
                }
                //System.out.println(nextNode.stringBuilder);
                //System.out.println(dirtExists);
                List<Node> possibleMoves;
                possibleMoves = successor(nextNode, grid);
                //System.out.println(possibleMoves.size());

                for(int i=0; i<possibleMoves.size(); i++){
                        Node temp = possibleMoves.get(i);
                        System.out.println("About to enter the queue " + temp.stringBuilder);

                        //Need to make sure this nextNode does not exist in explored OR the fifo already
                        //Dont worry about this, it still adds new unique nodes to the fifo, i just dont know why its adding it to the head 
                        if(compareNodes(temp, fifo, explored)){
                            //Then do not add because it is a duplicate
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Just got added to the queue " + temp.stringBuilder);
                            fifo.add(temp);
                        }
                }
                System.out.println("Head of the queue is: " + fifo.peek().stringBuilder);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**As Cody from below pointed out**

All I was passing the fifo variable into a method in which I was using the poll function. This caused the issue.

So I got rid of the polling I did in the function and just iterated through the queue.

Problem Solved!

Comment: First of all PQ is not FIFO. Could you please paste your Node class as well.

Comment: @cody123 Oh, I guess I miss understood what was meant in the Java docs when a PQ is created. > Creates a PriorityQueue that orders its elements according to their natural ordering. I also posted the node class

Comment: Can you please add input and output of above code?

Comment: Added input and output

Comment: And you are not using PQ right?? Because If u r using LL den your output doesn't add up.

Comment: Yah I'm not using priority right now. The output is from the LL implementation od a queue. I just need to figure out why it's adding the newest element as the head instead of at the tail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125245/discussion-between-cody123-and-vedhar).

Comment: compareNodes(temp, fifo, explored) what this method does? Can you share this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your method. Remove poll because it is removing from original list. You can directly use equals method, which you can generate in your Node class.

```
private static boolean compareNodes(Node currentNode, Queue<Node> fifo, ArrayList<Node> explored){
    boolean exists = false;
    while(!fifo.isEmpty()){
        exists = fifo.contains(currentNode);
        if(exists){
            //System.out.println("Exists in fifo");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(exists){

    }else{
        for(Node n: explored){
            if(n.equals(currentNode)){
                //System.out.println("Exists in explored");
                exists = true;
                break;
            }else{
                //keep on going
            }
        }
    }

    return exists;
}
```